# C# Linq nested selects not returning everything

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to select information from multiple tables via Linq. The query works if I take out the last Api query `from apis in Database.PluginApis where apis.PluginId == tenantPlugin.PluginId`. If I put the query back in, it results in an error `System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key 'Name' was not present in the dictionary.` Anyone able to see what I am doing wrong?

```
var results = (from tenantPlugin in Database.TenantPlugins
                           where tenantPlugin.TenantId == tenantId

                           select new TenantPlugin
                           {
                               PluginId = tenantPlugin.PluginId,
                               IsEnabled = tenantPlugin.IsEnabled,
                               TenantId = tenantPlugin.TenantId,
                               TenantPluginId = tenantPlugin.TenantPluginId,
                               Plugin = (from plugin in Database.Plugins
                                         where plugin.PluginId == tenantPlugin.PluginId
                                         select new Plugin
                                         {
                                             PluginId = plugin.PluginId,
                                             Name = plugin.Name,
                                             Description = plugin.Description,
                                             ImagePath = plugin.ImagePath,
                                             IsActive = plugin.IsActive,
                                             Apis = (from apis in Database.PluginApis
                                                         where apis.PluginId == tenantPlugin.PluginId                                                             
                                                     select new PluginApi
                                                     {
                                                         Name = apis.Name
                                                     }).ToList<PluginApi>()
                                         }).FirstOrDefault<Plugin>()
                           });

            return results.ToList();
```

Comment: What is relation between your tables? It seem (based on your query) that table `TenantPlugins` has 2 children as `Plugins` and `PluginApis` and those are joined on `PluginId`. But part of your query has been written as if `PluginApis` child of `Plugins`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's seems you have a perfect case to use `Include()` method. Try:

```
var results = Database.TenantPlugins
              .Include(t => t.Plugin.Select(p => p.Apis))
              .Where(t => t.TenantId == tenantId);
```